# Convert JSON to CSV1 and then compare the output with another CSV2, vb.net

Tags: json, csv

I am new to VB.net and have the following query.

How can I call an API in the vb.net code, extract JSON data from it and then convert this data into a CSV file. Once this is done, I need to compare this CSV with another CSV and pull out the difference.
Plz help

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Plz help. its urgent

Comment: I am still stuck...plz help